# Duplicating data while scroll tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have custom `UITableViewCell` with text field in it. The problem is after I enter some text in first text field (for example) this text duplicates in another cells after I scroll tableView. I know, this happens becouse tableView dequeue cells. 
What is correct way to handle this problem ? 
My code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

      var dataArray: [String] = []

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self

        for i in 0...50 {
          dataArray.append("Elemnt # \(i)")
        }
      }
    }

    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") 
        return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Right after you dequeue the cell in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can access its associated text field and clear it.

Alternatively, if you have subclassed `UITableViewCell`, you can override [`prepareForReuse()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) method in the subclass and do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your solution

Answer (score 1):

1 . You need to create one separate array with initial textValue :

```
 var stringArray:[String] = ["", "", "", ""]
```

2. Assign value to textField in cellForRowAtIndexpath

   ```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") 

    cell.textfield.text = stringArray[indexpath.row]  // change your swift syntax
   ```

3 . Replace that initial value in textFieldDidEndEditing .

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
          let buttonPosition:CGPoint = textField.convert(CGPointZero, 
           to:self.tableView)
          let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
          stringArray[indexPath.row] = textField.text
            println(allCellsText)
           self.tableView.reloadData() // or you can reload specific cell
        }
    }
```